# Don't know how to print a char array in my C code

Tags: c

I wrote the following code. But the when I add `%s` to print the name , the whole code stops after 1 iteration and either the `name[i]` or `t[i]` won't print. Code works fine if I don't add %s to print the name. Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code. Thank you. :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
int i,t1[3],t2[3],t3[3],t[3],avg=0;
char name[3];

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    printf("Enter the name:");
    scanf("%s",&name[i]);
    printf("Enter marks for test 1:");
    scanf("%d",&t1[i]);
    printf("Enter marks for test 2:");
    scanf("%d",&t2[i]);
    printf("Enter marks for test 3:");
    scanf("%d",&t3[i]);

    if(t1[i]<0 || t2[i]<0 || t3[i]<0 ||t1[i]>100 || t2[i]>100 || t3[i]>100 )
    {
        printf("Invalid score\n");
    }
    t[i]=t1[i]+t2[i]+t3[i];
    avg=avg+t[i];

    printf("%s : Total Score of = %d ",name[i],t[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: You say C# in the title, but C in the tags. Which is it?

Comment: `name` is just one string, not an array of 3 strings. It has room for 2 characters plus the null terminator. You're going out of bounds when you read the input.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your compiler should print some warning when you pass a single `char` where it expects a `char*`.  If it doesn't you should turn up warnings. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra`. If you get warnings during compilation, be sure to read them and take care about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` needs to be an array of strings, not an array of `char`.

```
char name[3][30];
```

Then you would use

```
scanf("%s", name[i]); // no need for & when passing an array
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to print a char using `%s`

> printf("%s : Total Score of = %d ",name[i],t[i]);

If you want to print a string you have to inizialize `name` as a string (an array of arrays):

> char name[3][20];